# Automatically relaunch VirtualBox VM when it crashes

Tags: crash, launchd, automation, virtualbox, daemons

Is there some way to automatically relaunch a VirtualBox VM if it happens to crash?

My VM occasionally crashes and has to be relaunched which I can do manually when I'm at my computer, but I'd like some way to relaunch it automatically in case it crashes when I'm not there to make sure it's running at all times (or just minimize downtime from when it crashes to when I notice it had crashed and start it up again).

I found in the [VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-startvm) how to launch a VM from the command line using:

```
VBoxManage startvm VM_to_start
```

Is there some way to trigger this command to run when the VM crashes, so that it starts again automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: So what about a chron task that checks if VM is running and if not runs it.

Comment: That sounds good. Any idea how would I set one up?